# Total count decreases in group by and sorting laravel app

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-6

I'm trying to build an application in `Laravel 6.0` where I'm having a sorting functionality where some of the sorting is done by joining the table as it is relational data. My code is:

```
$query->join('project_attribute_relation', 'projects.id', '=', 'project_attribute_relation.project_id')
    ->join('project_attributes', 'project_attribute_relation.attribute_id', 'project_attributes.id')
    ->select('projects.*', 'project_attributes.name as categories_name')
    ->groupBy('projects.id')
    ->orderBy('categories_name', request('sort_by_column')['order']);
```

My problem is the paginated data i.e. counts of total project becomes less during this sorting as it always counts the existing relational data and empty relation is ignored. But I want to have those empty relation also as it is effecting my project functionality.

This is my general list of projects:

[image: General project]

And this is my list when I do sorting with categories:

[image: Category Sorting]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are using Laravel's `join()`, that means you are using `innerjoin` to query, and the project with empty relation will be not included.

And if you want to display the project with empty relation,

you need to use `leftjoin`, so that the projects with empty relation will be included, code like this:

```php
$query->leftjoin('project_attribute_relation', 'projects.id', '=', 'project_attribute_relation.project_id')
    ->leftjoin('project_attributes', 'project_attribute_relation.attribute_id', 'project_attributes.id')
```